# Magento2 commands not running in chroot environment

Tags: server, php, chroot, magento

I successfully set a chroot on my server. I want to place magento projects on chroot so that a user can execute all sorts of magento2 commands if needed. I mounted magento projects to chroot directory. But when i run any of magento2 commands say "php bin/magento cache:clean" I get the following error:

> php: error while loading shared libraries: libresolv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

After copying all the required libraries i get the following error:

> Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'UTC' is invalid in /home/user/myapp/app/bootstrap.php on line 63
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/user/myapp/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/user/myapp/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('
>
> 1 /home/user/myapp/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('

Please help me to get through this error.. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you seen this answer yet?
https://askubuntu.com/a/1122878/1144775
it covers your topic in details/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of struggling, I finally found a solution... I had to combine JailKit and some other commands. This made everything work for me just as i wanted.

Comment: if you can post your solution that would be great i am running php 7 and not able to run any php, mysql commands and nano editors inside jail (jailkit) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To run any command inside the chroot, you should have this program available in the chroot (since it cannot use the program installed in the / of filesystem.
You might requirement parts of /dev, /bin, /etc, /usr, /lib (and probably others also) installed suitably under the new root directory. Symlinks back to 'outside the chroot() environment' won't work, in overall. If you impartial want the ls command, you'll quiet need to copy extra than ls. To run ls, you'll need to copy the ls command as well as all the files it be contingent on.